How to set Selenium version of Chrome as Default Browser
Essentially as the title says, I am trying to use Selenium to automate some aspects of my job. But Selenium when initialized opens a unique version of Chrome so if I happen to click a link in lets say an Excel Doc or Teams then that link opens in a different Chrome than the one Selenium is using.
I am not sure what to try here to get links to open with the Selenium version of Chrome rather than the default version of Chrome as I am rather new to coding.
Here is my current code that initializes the browser:
def initialize_browser():
    global driver
    opt = Options()
    profile_path = r'C:\Users\users_name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default'
    opt.add_argument(f'user-data-dir={profile_path}')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt)
    driver.get("Website I initially load") # Login URL
    messagebox.showinfo("Login Required", "Please log in manually in the opened browser window. Close this message box once logged in.")

So I am wondering is there a way to make it to where if I click a link that it will instead open with the Chrome Browser that Selenium opens by default instead.

@user24714692 I have just tried this method but it still does not allow clicked links to open in the version of Chrome opened by Selenium. It continues to open the default Chrome Browser instead.

So from what I understand what I am requesting is not possible or may be difficult to accomplish. I have found out that there is a browser based version of our tool so I am going to use that as the original initialized browser page and attempt to work off of that.
